# How to jump if the AF flag is 1?

Tags: assembly, emu8086, eflags

I want to check if auxiliary carry flag is 1 then do something. I can't find any reference regarding only auxiliary carry flag.

```
mov al,00011010b
mov bl,10011010b  
add al,bl
;jump  if AF == 1
```

Comment: You mean the AF flag bit in [FLAGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register)?  (AL is a register.)  You can't branch on AF directly in a single instruction; you have to transfer it to a register, e.g. with `lahf`, then test the bit.

Comment: sorry for the typo, i ment to wirte a AF flag bit but get mix up with the AL, thanks for the ANSWEAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no conditional jumps based on AF.  The easiest solution, as Peter Cordes said, is to load the flags onto the stack or into AH and branch on that:

```
add al, bl    ; some operation that sets AF
lahf          ; load flags into AH
test ah, 10h  ; check if AF is set
jnz afset     ; branch to afset if AF was set
```

Alternatively, if you are willing to trash AL, you can use `aaa` on value `00h` to check if half carry occured.

```
add al, bl    ; some operation that sets AF
mov al, 0     ; clear AL for testing
aaa           ; set CF = AF, trash AX
jc afset     ; branch to afset if AF was set
```

Comment: [`aaa` is similar but doesn't care about the incoming CF](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aaa).  With AL=0, it sets CF=AF (and clobbers the whole AX, but does save the `clc` instruction).  You do still need to zero AL every time even if in a loop; doing it twice would leave AL = 6 + 6 = `0xc` and set AF=CF=1 regardless of incoming AF.